# How to call SIOCSIFHWADDR ioctl to change MAC address in Python?

Tags: python, c, linux

So I have Python code which creates a Linux TAP interface, but it always comes up with a random, auto-generated MAC address. To simplify testing I would like to manually assign the interface a MAC address after it has been initialized. I know I can do this with the `SIOCSIFHWADDR` ioctl and `struct ifreq`, but I had a few questions about the implementation.

Here is the C struct:

```
struct ifreq
{
# define IFHWADDRLEN    6
# define IFNAMSIZ       IF_NAMESIZE
union
  {
    char ifrn_name[IFNAMSIZ];       /* Interface name, e.g. "en0".  */
  } ifr_ifrn;

union
  {
    struct sockaddr ifru_addr;
    struct sockaddr ifru_dstaddr;
    struct sockaddr ifru_broadaddr;
    struct sockaddr ifru_netmask;
    struct sockaddr ifru_hwaddr;
    short int ifru_flags;
    int ifru_ivalue;
    int ifru_mtu;
    struct ifmap ifru_map;
    char ifru_slave[IFNAMSIZ];      /* Just fits the size */
    char ifru_newname[IFNAMSIZ];
    __caddr_t ifru_data;
  } ifr_ifru;
};
```

Now I think that I only need to fill in the `hwaddr` field, but this being a union I am not sure how to create the structure in Python.

What is the best way to call the `SIOCSIFHWADDR` ioctl with `struct ifreq` to change an interface's MAC address in Python?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to do it in Python or in C?

Comment: In Python, my main problem is building the structure to pass to the ioctl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

from: http://nullege.com/codes/show/src@p@y@pynetlinux-1.0@pynetlinux@ifconfig.py

```
def set_mac(self, newmac):
    ''' Set the device's mac address. Device must be down for this to
        succeed. '''
    macbytes = [int(i, 16) for i in newmac.split(':')]
    ifreq = struct.pack('16sH6B8x', self.name, AF_UNIX, *macbytes)
    fcntl.ioctl(sockfd, SIOCSIFHWADDR, ifreq)
```

I've used a lot of the networking methods from that module; very useful!

Comment: I wish I knew of that module before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A `union` simply means that there are multiple ways to think about the content.  You're only interested in one, this one:

```
struct ifreq_set_hwaddr
{
# define IFHWADDRLEN    6
# define IFNAMSIZ       IF_NAMESIZE
    char ifrn_name[IFNAMSIZ];       /* Interface name, e.g. "en0".  */
    struct sockaddr ifru_hwaddr;
};
```

Note that I've assumed that `struct sockaddr` has the same (or strictest) alignment requirement as the other union members.  If not, you may need some padding.

Answer (score 0):

You spawn /sbin/ip as a subprocess e.g.

```
/sbin/ip link set dev dummy0 address 02:23:45:67:89:ab
```

which will save a lot of hassle.